# Two Column Layout with heavy technical restrictions

Tags: html, css

I have to work with a CMS where I do not have access to stylesheets. Internal css commands in the sense of `style="width:200px"` are being filtered by the CMS and hence cannot be used, neither.

The editor does not allow to add `align="left"` to images. Neither I can add this manually through the source code view.

What I want to achieve: a two column design - images to the left, text to the right (see wireframe).
[image]

Given the restrictions above, the only option I see for achieving this is using tables for image and text positioning. The problem is: the (for me not editable) theme has the following css attributes for the img tag:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Causing the images to shrink in Safari depending on the amount of text in the adjacent cells...
For Firefox everything works fine.

Does anyone have a clue what I could do?

I suppose removing `max-width: 100%;` would be the easiest solution. But is there another solution which would avoid changes to the stylesheet (since I do not have access to it)?

Comment: Sometimes, you just have to come in terms with the fact that you cannot achieve everything under heavy restrictions. Good luck.

Comment: If you're thinking of using tables for it, How are you putting the tables in ? You have access to the html then use inline styles via js on page load, that should get around cms filtering

Comment: When I add java script with source code view, this is being filtered as well...

Comment: What CMS is this? It seems like it's very old technology to disallow access to CSS and JS in content.

Comment: By the way, using tables for layout isn't really a good idea.

Comment: @abhitalks I know. But sometimes you do not have the choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If you have *absolutely* no other choice

### Old school table layout with obsolete attributes

---

**Disclaimer:** I in no way endorse tables for layouts; they are meant for tabular data. This answer is purely given for the purposes of demonstrating a work around within the limitations laid out in the question.

---

### Styling the table

Basically, go to the [MDN documentation on `<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) and use all the obsolete attributes it tells you not to use:

- **valign** - for vertical alignment in cells
- **cellpadding** - for padding in cells
- **cellspacing** - for gaps between cells
- **bgcolor** - for background color
- **width**
- **height**
- **border**

(This feels dirty, but so many memories)

The [`<colgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) and [`<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col)  elements could also help. They are still in the current HTML spec as well, which is nice :)

Hell, let's go crazy and center it with `<center>` (eww!). Sometimes you need to work with what you have.

### Reset the image width

So as we discussed in the comments, you found that your archaic CMS allows a style attribute on the image element. Use a max-width value to override the 100% value set in your stylesheet:

```
style="max-width: 1000px; width: 134px;"
```

### Let's kick it old school!

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <table cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" style="max-width: 1000px; width: 134px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus gravida venenatis. Nam nisl sem, fringilla vel tempor id, congue a erat. Fusce venenatis dapibus purus ac hendrerit. Morbi in ullamcorper ligula, in varius lorem.
        </p>
        <p>Donec consectetur faucibus vehicula. Nulla semper facilisis nisi vel faucibus. Sed posuere id nibh eu finibus. In id nunc non diam laoreet efficitur vel vel ligula. Nam vitae sollicitudin mi. Phasellus dapibus sem non nisl volutpat, vitae euismod
          quam ullamcorper.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" style="max-width: 1000px; width: 134px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus gravida venenatis. Nam nisl sem, fringilla vel tempor id, congue a erat. Fusce venenatis dapibus purus ac hendrerit. Morbi in ullamcorper ligula, in varius lorem.
        </p>
        <p>Donec consectetur faucibus vehicula. Nulla semper facilisis nisi vel faucibus. Sed posuere id nibh eu finibus. In id nunc non diam laoreet efficitur vel vel ligula. Nam vitae sollicitudin mi. Phasellus dapibus sem non nisl volutpat, vitae euismod
          quam ullamcorper.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

### So how can we give this table a width?

#### Did someone say spacer.gif?!

Yes! We are back in 2002!

**This is truly horrible**, but it might work with the right combination of CSS width / max-width

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FFFFFF" style="max-width: 500px;width: 20%; height: 1000px; float: right;" />
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/FFFFFF" style="max-width: 500px;width: 20%; height: 1000px; float: left;" />
  <table cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" style="max-width: 1000px; width: 134px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus gravida venenatis. Nam nisl sem, fringilla vel tempor id, congue a erat. Fusce venenatis dapibus purus ac hendrerit. Morbi in ullamcorper ligula, in varius lorem.
        </p>
        <p>Donec consectetur faucibus vehicula. Nulla semper facilisis nisi vel faucibus. Sed posuere id nibh eu finibus. In id nunc non diam laoreet efficitur vel vel ligula. Nam vitae sollicitudin mi. Phasellus dapibus sem non nisl volutpat, vitae euismod
          quam ullamcorper.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" style="max-width: 1000px; width: 134px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In faucibus gravida venenatis. Nam nisl sem, fringilla vel tempor id, congue a erat. Fusce venenatis dapibus purus ac hendrerit. Morbi in ullamcorper ligula, in varius lorem.
        </p>
        <p>Donec consectetur faucibus vehicula. Nulla semper facilisis nisi vel faucibus. Sed posuere id nibh eu finibus. In id nunc non diam laoreet efficitur vel vel ligula. Nam vitae sollicitudin mi. Phasellus dapibus sem non nisl volutpat, vitae euismod
          quam ullamcorper.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help and inspiration! Unfortunately giving `td`a width results in an error message from the cms...
I think it won't work without adjustments of the cms administrator...

Comment: Oh, wow. It does get even more adventurous. The system does also return an error, when a width is being added to the `table` tag.

But: surprisingly the system allows me to add a `style` attribute to the `img` tag. So when I determine via css an image width of 400px it nearly gets the desired width of 134px. But now (logically) the image turns out to be too big in Firefox. Since in Firefox the css size is being implemented the right way...

Comment: And no, `style` attributes for `div` tags are being filtered again - so I cannot set up a two column layout the proper modern way.

Comment: ! Try `style="max-width: 1000px; width: 134px;"` on the image element. (Basically, override the max width inline)

Comment: Consider yourself as the hero of the day! Thanks a thousand times! This seems to actually work!
Would you mind to write an answer, that I will accept?

Comment: Hahaha - wow ok. Awesome! Answer updated to reflect this find :D

Comment: Nope. The system does not allow to specify a table width.

Comment: Have a look at the snippet I made at the very bottom of my answer. Truly horrible, but I am enjoying myself way too much.

Comment: Haha! I see, you are enjoying yourself :-D